# 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing my code, and trying to reassign the input variable (`YourName`) to only include the letters, and to disregard any numbers (if that makes sense)

```
while YourName == None:
    YourName = (input("But before we begin, what is your name?:")) #The name can be anything.
    YourName = YourName.capitalize()
    YourName = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha(YourName), input))
```

But when I run it comes up with 'method' not iterable.

How do I fix this

Comment: `input` is a function ... it is not  iterable ... it cannot be passed to filter or join

Comment: I guess you meant `filter(str.isalpha, YourName)`?

Comment: What is the point of the `while` loop?  It will never run more than once, as `YourName` will definitely not be equal to `None` after the first loop iteration (it might be _empty_, but that's not the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use filter, the line should be as follows

```
YourName = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, YourName))
```

Full program

```
YourName = None

while YourName == None:
    YourName = (input("But before we begin, what is your name?:")) #The name  can be anything.
    YourName = YourName.capitalize()
    YourName = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, YourName))
    print(YourName)
```

Sample output

```
But before we begin, what is your name?:1231af 45 sdfsd
afsdfsd
```

NOTE: You are missing out the spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`

```
import re

YourName = None

while YourName == None:
    YourName = (input("But before we begin, what is your name?:")) #The name  can be anything.
    YourName = YourName.capitalize()
    YourName = re.sub(r'\d+', '', YourName)
    print(YourName)
```

Sample output

```
But before we begin, what is your name?:ada64782jhadas
Adajhadas
```